# Crash every time we type Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, command-line, crash

I am learning recently mobile apps development using Flutter, and I am trynna to install the Flutter Fire cli using my command prompt, but every time that I type the command to install the firebase the command prompt crashes without any message. I tried to type dart in the command prompt and the same problem appears. The command prompt crashes only when I type dart, knowing that I have installed the latest version of Dart SDK on my pc.
Please if anyone knows how to solve this problem, it would be great and thankful if you help me resolve it.
Thanks

I have uninstalled dart sdk and reinstalled it, asked Chat GPT to help me but no good answer and searched all over google and no answer